# System.Drawing out of memory but only in standalone

Tags: c#, multithreading, build, out-of-memory

I'm having a sort of strange issue.

I have a program that converts massive amounts of TIF files to PDFs. It only needs to run once on about 40k files but I've been testing with about 200.

On the server I'm running it on, it crashes with an out of memory exception (in System.Drawing), normally I'd figure I did something dumb and at first, I thought it was because more conversion threads are created on the server than my dev box. So I tried it with 1 thread and it still crashed. Mind you, when running the app in Visual Studio on my desktop it had been running fine this whole time.

So I opened the solution on the server itself so I could run it in the debugger and see what is happening specifically. To my amazement, it ran fine. All files converted even with the max threads raised again. What's more, the EXE generated by the server runs fine standalone. So it only happens to builds generated on my desktop, then sent over to the server. I've tried a few build settings but it's not the end of the world since I can build and run there. I just was curious as to why it might be happening.

For reference, the server is running Server 2008R2 and my desktop is running Windows 7. Both 64-bit. I tried building 32-bit only and 64-bit only and neither made a difference so it's back to default now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the operating system on the server? What is your platform target for your build, both on your own machine and on the server?

Comment: This could be a bug. As in, not a memory issue at all -- the GDI classes are prone to giving misleading or incorrect error messages when invoked with invalid parameters. It's a shame you've got a heisenbug that disappears when you hook up a debugger, or you could verify that you're not just passing invalid data to calls.

Comment: @MattJones I have added that information to the question.

Comment: @JeroenMostert It wouldn't surprise me, I already found another bug out of my control in the process of building this.

Comment: smells like a missing `using`

Comment: If you really want to get to the bottom of it, use `procdump` from the SysInternals tools to capture a dump at the crash, then `windbg` with `sos` to get the actual stack trace and memory situation. Not as convenient as live debugging, but reliable.

Comment: In this sort of situation, I usually stick an abundance of logging in - at least then you might get something useful when you run it on the server in the set up that gets the crashes. Do you have any stack trace info from the exception?

Comment: @pm100 I would be happy if that ended up being the case, but why would it even compile? (I'm just curious if a situation exists in C#/.NET where VS would allow that)

Comment: @JeroenMostert I'll have to give that a shot, I really want to know why it's different from one build to another using the exact same version of VS and all.

Comment: @MattJones I usually do the same and I did do that a little bit, maybe I'll be a little more verbose and see if I can at lease figure out where it dies.

Comment: I've always taken the opinion that running non-trivial (CPU/Memory intensive) conversions in the server process is a bad idea, as they can quite easily take down the server. I now have a strong preference for spawning the conversion as a separate process and gathering the result via STDOUT. E.g. the standalone exe does the work. IIRC there are very good reasons not to use GDI in the server process.

Comment: things compile perfectly well if you miss out a using - its one of the main weaknesses with the dispose mechanism; the library writer cannot force the caller to use using